# Typescript array confusion - TS 2488 with Type 'never'

Tags: arrays, typescript, compiler-errors, iterable

They is the following code errors on the for loop with TS 2488 for the type of apps - which at the time is of type never?

If I remove the 3rd comparison in the if, **Array.isArray(apps)**, then the the type is correct in the for loop (ILuisApp[]) instead of type never.

```
export interface ILuisFull {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    culture: string;
    versionsCount: number;
    app_createdDateTime: string;
    endpointHitsCount: number;
    activeVersion: string;
    tokenizerVersion: string;
  }
  export interface ILuisApp {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    culture: string;
    usageScenario: string;
    domain: string;
    versionsCount: number;
    createdDateTime: string;
    endpointHitsCount: number;
    activeVersion: string;
    ownerEmail?: string;
    tokenizerVersion: string;
  }

export const transform = (apps: ILuisApp[]): ILuisFull[] => {

    if (!apps || apps.length === 0 || Array.isArray(apps)) return [] as ILuisFull[];

    let fullTable: Array<ILuisFull> = [];

    // apps is type never unless remove 3rd comparison in if above
    for (var val of apps) {
        console.log(val);
      }
    return fullTable;
}
```

ts config includes:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "es2017.object",
  "esnext.asynciterable"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like compiler thinks that `apps` is not initialized. It thinks that `arr` is `null`. So it says:

> Type 'never' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an
>   iterator.

However, it is possible to use casting `apps as ILuisApp[])` to say what type of `apps` is:

```
for (let val of apps as ILuisApp[]) {
    console.log(val);
}
```